# what's the best way to get etherpad to launch on startup on OSX

Tags: macos, launchd, etherpad

I think launchd is the answer, but using this plist:

http://gist.github.com/553573

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/appjet/oui/main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.appjet.oui.main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the content of `/usr/local/etherpad/trunk/etherpad/bin/run-local.sh` referred to from the plist??

Comment: Hi - It's the startup script bundled with the default install: contents here:

http://gist.github.com/554102

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classpath problems perhaps? The script /usr/local/etherpad/trunk/etherpad/bin/run-local.sh  is supposed to be started from a specific directory (path). Try editing your copy to start with a cd command to go the right folder just before it creates subfolders data/appjet.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. In retrospect should have poked around that file a bit more. Would upvote you but I'm new here.